# Is MinGW caching Windows directory contents?

Tags: caching, mingw, directory-listing

Can anyone explain this?:

**From Windows 7 Pro command prompt:**

```
C:\Users\dbanas>dir C:\Windows\System32\*.h
Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume Serial Number is FCC9-2CA2

Directory of C:\Windows\System32

09/18/2013  06:05 AM            85,172 curses.h
09/18/2013  06:05 AM             2,488 panel.h
06/10/2009  01:59 PM             1,820 rasctrnm.h
               3 File(s)         89,480 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  308,851,462,144 bytes free
```

**From Github shell (MinGW32):**

```
dbanas@DBANAS-LAP ~/Documents/GitHub/hermit (master)
$ ls -a /c/Windows/System32/*.h
/c/Windows/System32/rasctrnm.h
```

The only thing that jumps out at me is the fact that the date/time stamps of the two files missing from the MinGW32 listing are very recent. Is MinGW caching Windows directory contents?! If so, how do I tell it to rebuild its cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git MINGW `bash` is a 32-bit program and therefore it is subject to the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on 64 bit systems.

You shouldn't be storing header files in the system32 directory, anyway.